# Why does hadoop partitioner do a binary AND?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, partitioner

I'm completely new to Hadoop and fairly new to Map/Reduce so bear with me if this is a very simple question.

In hadoop's hash partitioner, why does it do a hash(key) & Integer.MAX_VALUE before doing a modulo with the number of reducers? What is the point of the binary AND?